# Setting View Controller Storyboard ID Doesn't Work

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this code to transition to another view controller (I would like to do this programmatically due to the fact that the app has many viewControllers all of which connect to each other):

```
UIViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:0 completion:nil];
```

I also set the `Storyboard ID` of the viewController to `HomeViewController` in the storyboard file.

When I run it I get the error: `'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x712af50>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'HomeViewController''`

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the `Storyboard ID` in the storyboard there are a couple of fields there. Also did you click (or tab) away from the `Storyboard ID` field after editing it? If you don't click away it sometimes doesn't update the underlying xml

Comment: @Paul.s I am sure that I have set the Storyboard ID. I am assuming that it updated because when I go to my code and back to the storyboard, the field is not empty.

Comment: Is the curser still in that field when you return to it (basically just make sure that you have ended editing the text field? Are you sure that you are editing the storyboard file that `self.storyboard` is returning?

Comment: @Paul.s The field is no longer selected. I am not sure what self.storyboard returns. Any suggestions for how to find out?

Comment: Do you have multiple storyboards? Is the viewController that is calling `self.storyboard` from that storyboard?

Comment: @Paul.s Only one storyboard. The calling viewController is from that storyboard.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the identifier is exactly the same e.g. a copy and paste from the code to the storyboard

Comment: @Paul.s Copy and pasted. Still get the exact same error.

Comment: If you are sure it's 100% spelt exactly the same and using the same storyboard. Try delete the build from the sim, do a full clean of the build folder (⌥⇧⌘K) and restart Xcode.

Comment: @Paul.s Followed your instructions. Now the error has changed and I do not understand it: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/carloabelli/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/04B60F46-EF10-43FA-B96F-A8F138EF99BC/Nobles.app> (loaded)'`

Comment: Is there a storyboard named `Storyboard` in your project?

Comment: @Paul.s Yes the storyboard is named `Storyboard.storyboard`

Comment: Is it in your current target? Click on the storyboard file then hit ⌥⌘1 to show the `File Inspector` and make sure that there is a tick in the `Target Membership` area next to the current target

Comment: Can you confirm that it is included in the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase of your `Build Phases`?

Comment: @Paul.s It is included.

Comment: Can you see your storyboard file inside `/Users/carloabelli/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/04B60F46-EF10-43FA-B96F-A8F138EF99BC/Nobles.app`. Do you have multiple targets set up?

Comment: @Paul.s The storyboard file is inside. I don't think I have multiple targets set up.

Comment: Did you try nuking it all? Delete app from sim, clean build, restart xcode?

Comment: @Paul.s Yes that is what caused this new error.

Comment: Can you confirm that the name of your storyboard is an exact match (case sensitive) of the name used in the `Summary` tab of your target settings

Comment: @Paul.s It is. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: @Paul.s I copied the code to a different location and ran it from there and now it no longer gives the storyboard error. Just the original error from the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I just clean the project and delete the app from my simulator or phone and run it again. It worked.